# Lazy loading of images using Alamofire and AlamofireImage Not working at first Load

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, alamofire, alamofireimage

So I am trying to follow the mvc architecture in this app. Here is the code for the image part.

**Model**

```
   import Alamofire
   import AlamofireImage

    class Brands {
    private var _image : UIImage!
    var image : UIImage {
        if _image == nil {
           _image = UIImage(named: "loadingImage")
        }
        return _image
    }

    init(BrandsDict : Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){
      if let imageUrl = BrandsDict["imageUrl"] as? String{
         Alamofire.request(imageUrl).responseImage(completionHandler: { (response) in
                    guard let image = response.result.value else {
                        self._image = UIImage(named: "loadingImage")
                        return
                    }
                    self._image = image

                 })
       }else {
       self._image = UIImage(named : "loadingImage")
    }
```

**View**

```
class BrandsCVCell : UICollectionViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var BrandImage : UIImageView!

  var brand : Brands!

  func configureCell(_ brand : Brands){
   self.brand = brand
   BrandImage.image = self.brand.image
}
}
```

**Controller**

inViewDidLoad
    ....

```
if let jsonArray = data as? NSArray {
                for objects in jsonArray {
                    let Brand = Brands(BrandsDict: objects as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
                    self.Brands.append(Brand)
                }
               self.bestBrandCollection.reloadData()
            }

....

if collectionView == BrandCollection {
 if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "BrandsCell", for: indexPath) as? BrandCollectionViewCell {

                let Brand = Brands[indexPath.row]
                cell.configureCell(Brand)
                return cell
            }else {
                return UICollectionViewCell()
            }
}
```

The problem is that when the images are loaded in the collection view the cells which are in display does not get the downloaded images but when i scroll them the earlier cells get their images. Can somebody help me to lazy load the images after they are downloaded. (maybe completion handler but i don't know where to put it). Coded answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is image which downloaded from network is not refreshed to the cell after downloading. You need to callback in `Alamofire.request` block. Solution:

**First**, add the block to callback in model:

```
class Brands {
    //......
    public var imageDidDownload:(()->Void)?  //Key point, declare a callback block

    init(BrandsDict : Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){
        if let imageUrl = BrandsDict["imageUrl"] as? String{
            Alamofire.request(imageUrl).responseImage(completionHandler: { (response) in
                //......
                self._image = image
                self.imageDidDownload?() //Key point, callback after image downloaded
                //......
            })
        }else {
            //......
        }
    }
}
```

**Second**, in cell, to handle the image downloaded callback to refresh the image:

```
class BrandsCVCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    //......
    func configureCell(_ brand : Brands){
        self.brand = brand
        self.brand.imageDidDownload = { [weak self]() -> Void in
            self?.BrandImage.image = self?.brand.image  //Key point, refresh image to the imageView after downloading.
        } 
        BrandImage.image = self.brand.image
    }
}
```

Try it, should work.

Comment: where should i put self.imageDidDownload?() in initializer

Comment: Well now the all of the cells images are not getting downlloaded and showing blank also not showing the loading image.

Comment: Keep your code, just add what I added. self.imageDidDownload?() is after self._image = image. Is your code like this?

Comment: Maybe the original BrandImage.image = self.brand.image is lost. Could you check it? I also updated the answer's configureCell method.

Comment: Yeah.. It is working fine as expected. The images the loading lazily after they are downloaded. Thanks again.  Have a nice day.

Comment: Glad to help, ;)